# Math problem puzzle

Tags: problem-solving

My grandson is about as many days as my son in weeks, and my grandson is as many months as I am in years. My grandson, my son and I together are 120 years. Can you tell me my age in years ?

It's really simple : The above system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns can be solved as follows.

I know the solution should i write it ?

Comment: if you know the answer why post this question? this isn't very interesting either. then why?

Comment: I thought i have the right to post a question that i already know the answer of it

Comment: I guess you do, but the convention is that you only post a question when you need help, or when you think that posting this question will help someone else, i.e, add value to the community. this is neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $x, y,\text{ and } z$ are the ages of your grandson, your son, and you respectively, expressed in years, then your system is:

$$365x = 52y$$
$$12x=z$$
$$x+y+z=120$$

Therefore $x=6$, $y=42$ and $z=72$

Answer (score 1):

Your son is $7$ times as old as your grandson. You are $12$ times as old as your grandson. Therefore if you let $x$ denote the age of your grandson, you have
$$x + 7x + 12x =20x = 120$$
It follows that your grandson is $6$ years old, your son is $42$ years old and you are $72$ years old.